# Preload all CSS images while showing a preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, background-image

I have a website heavily loaded with images. It's quite unattractive to see the images coming up slowly. I've seen a few websites show a preloader which hides that ugly loading phase. I'm not talking about the `<img />` tag here, but I'm talking about CSS `background-image`s.

I do not understand how to achieve this effect using JavaScript and/or jQuery.

P.S: I also seeking links to plugins if there are any available.

Comment: Google is your best friend: https://gist.github.com/darryl-snow/3822494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start of with setting the css:

```
#myElement
{
    background-image: url('loading.gif');
}
```

Then use the following javascript function:

```
function loadImage()
{
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = "http://path/to/img";
    img.onload = function() 
    {
        var myElement = document.getElementById("myElement");
        myElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + this.src + "')";
    }
}
```

fire the function in the body onload like this:

```
<body onload="loadImage();">
```

or add it to another init script which fires from here.

Hope this will get you going!